# How can I obtain correct non-ASCII command-line arguments in ActiveState Perl?

Tags: perl, internationalization, cmd, activestate

Running the following command

```
perl -e "for (my $i = 0; $i < length($ARGV[0]); $i++) {print ord(substr($ARGV[0], $i, 1)), qq{\n}; }" αβγδεζ
```

on a Windows 7 cmd window with ActiveState Perl v5.14.2 produces the following result:

```
97
223
63
100
101
63
```

The above values are nonsensical and don't correspond to any known encoding, so trying to decode them with the approach recommended in
[How can I treat command-line arguments as UTF-8 in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037467/how-can-i-treat-command-line-arguments-as-utf-8-in-perl) doesn't help. Changing the command window active code page doesn't change the results.

Comment: This might not help you, but out of curiosity I tried on my Linux terminal set to use UTF-8, with Perl 5.12.4 After changing the quoting style to single quotes to avoid the shell interpreting the $ variables I got: 206 177 206 178 206 179 206 180 206 181 206 182 - I checked the first letter alpha and is correct, so I think it's the correct result.

Comment: Single quotes don't work on Windows, and I believe the correct results are `945 946 947 948 949 950` (http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/bylanguage/greekchart.html#greeklower)

Comment: How did you type the characters on the command line? Did you copy and paste from some other program?

Comment: @MisterEd yes you're right. My output didn't lose any information but is a byte by byte output as opposed to a character by character output, which I can obtain with -CA switch as you suggested. Happy to have learnt something, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your system, like every Windows system I know, uses by default the 1252 ANSI code page, so you could try to use

```
use Encode qw( decode );
@ARGV = map { decode('cp1252', $_) } @ARGV;
```

Note that cp1252 cannot represent all of those characters, which is why the console and thus Perl actually receives

- a 97
- ß 223
- ? 63
- d 100
- e 101
- ? 63

There is a "Wide" interface for passing (almost) any Unicode code point to a program, but

1. The Wide interface is not used when you type in a command at the prompt.
2. Perl uses the ANSI interface to fetch the parameters, so even if you started Perl using the Wide interface, the parameters would get downgraded to ANSI when Perl fetches them.

Sorry, but this is a "you can't" type of situation. You need a different approach. Diomidis Spinellis suggests changing your system's ANSI code page as follows in Win7:

1. Control Panel
2. Region and Language
3. Administrative
4. Language for non-Unicode programs
5. Set the Current language for non-Unicode programs to the language associated with the specific characters (Greek in your case).

At this point, you'd use the encoding of the ANSI code page associated with the new selected encoding instead of `cp1252` (`cp1253` for Greek).

```
use Encode qw( decode );
@ARGV = map { decode('cp1253', $_) } @ARGV;
```

Note that using `chcp` to modify the code page used within the console window does not affect the code page in which Perl receives its arguments, which is always an ANSI code page.  See the examples below (cp737 is the Greek [OEM code page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page#OEM_code_page), and cp1253 is the Greek [ANSI code page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page#ANSI_code_page).  You can find the encodings labeled as 37 and M7 in [this document](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1947.txt).)

```
C:\>chcp 737
Active code page: 737

C:\>echo αβγδεζ | od -t x1
0000000 98 99 9a 9b 9c 9d 20 0d 0a

C:\>perl -e "print map sprintf('%x ', ord($_)), split(//, $ARGV[0])" αβγδεζ
e1 e2 e3 e4 e5 e6

C:\>chcp 1253
Active code page: 1253

C:\>echo αβγδεζ | od -t x1
0000000 e1 e2 e3 e4 e5 e6 20 0d 0a

C:\>perl -e "print map sprintf('%x ', ord($_)), split(//, $ARGV[0])" αβγδεζ
e1 e2 e3 e4 e5 e6
```

Comment: @Diomidis Spinellis. I am reverting your edits because `chcp` uses returns the OEM code page, but I believe Perl receives the arguments encoded using the ANSI code page. `chcp` will only work if they happen to be the same.

Comment: You're right regarding chcp, and I provided an example to illustrate it.  There are many OEM code pages, and selecting the right one provides a solution.  I modified the answer accordingly; I hope you agree.

Comment: @Diomidis Spinellis, I just had time for a very quick look, but if I'm correctly guessing what you're saying, this is very interesting and useful information. I'll read it in detail tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (on OS-X, but should be portable):

```
echo  αβγδεζ |perl -CI -e "chomp($in=<STDIN>);for (my $i = 0; $i < length($in); $i++) {print ord(substr($in, $i, 1)), qq{\n}; }"
```

That was for STDIN; for ARGV:

```
perl -CA -e "for (my $i = 0; $i < length($ARGV[0]); $i++) {print ord(substr($ARGV[0], $i, 1)), qq{\n}; }" αβγδεζ
```

See the `-C` option in perlrun: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches

Comment: Sorry.  I get
97
Malformed UTF-8 character (unexpected non-continuation byte 0x3f, immediately after start byte 0xdf) in ord at -e line 1.
0
100
101
63
It is a Windows cmd issue, I'm sure it works fine on Linux, Mac OS X, etc.

Comment: Interesting, I wonder if it has to do with the Windows command line. Does it work if the characters are read from file and/or if the code is put into a script vice `-e`?

Comment: where do you run your script? from inside a cmd shell? If yes, have you tried starting cmd with /U switch?

Comment: That's not portable. That only works in UTF-8 locales. The OP definitely does not have a UTF-8 locale.

Answer (score 0):

If I place the characters in a file (from OS-X), copy it to a windows box (as `file.txt`), then run:

```
perl -CI -e "chomp($_=<STDIN>); map{print ord, qq{\n}} split(//)" < file.txt
```

Then I get the expected:

```
946
947
948
949
950
```

But if I copy the contents of `file.txt` to the command line, I get gibberish.

As @ikegami was saying, I don't think it's possible to do from command line since you don't have a UTF-8 locale.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Unicode::Native. It should have what you need.