# How to escape special characters of a shell argument

Tags: php, shell, shell-exec

I'm trying to send a string as a shell argument via `system()` in php.

Everything works fine until I send a string with special characters like this one **"Œ"** in particular. So, when I send this string **"ŒDucks"** the shell just recieves **"Ducks"**

I've tried escaping it adding "/", "\", simple quotes but it doesnt matter, I get the same result

This is my code:

```
system('/usr/bin/perl /var/prof/info.pl'.' '.EscapeShellArg("ŒDucks") > /dev/null &');
```

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: What happens if you set `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");` (or any utf-8 locale you have handy) before it?

Comment: Uhmm, interesting I just did it and I got this character "Å" instead "Œ"

Comment: Hm, what _is_ the character set in you PHP application?

Comment: **utf8_spanish_ci** 
Guessing that is the same as the Data Base where I'm extracting the string

Comment: And what _is_ the character set your Perl thing expects? `Å.. something` usually means it interprets _valid_ utf-8 (so it now survives the transport) as iso-8859-1* or similar (so it doesn't survive interpretation at the receiving end). (Also: be very sure about your database connection: do you set it _explicitly_ to utf-8? For `mysql`, a `SET NAMES utf8;` would do it).

Comment: Good question, how can I check what character set uses my PERL. I just started using it =S

Comment: Hm, that's out of my comfort zone, [but it seems to have been asked on SO before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037467/how-can-i-treat-command-line-arguments-as-utf-8-in-perl)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help, I'll read that forum and try to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

Try: `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");` or whatever locale that weirdness :) is from.

Comment: I just did it and I got this character "Å" instead "Œ"
Looks like I need to find the right locale

Comment: Yes, apologies, I am one of those English only people and have had rare instances when I have to deal with anything other than that.